# Return does not work in vba function procedure outlook 2010

Tags: vba, outlook

Why won't this work:

```
Private Function AddTwoNumbers(ByVal N1 As Integer, ByVal N2 As Integer) As Integer
    Return N1 + N2
End Function
```

I was following a code example from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74dh43ez%28v=vs.100%29.aspx but in Outlook 2010 I got a compile error for the `Return N1 + N2`

Comment: You're looking at the documentation for Visual Studio 2005/2008, i.e. VB.NET, not VBA.

Comment: my head in the clouds unreachable for clear reflection of me chosing the wrong tutorial... thanks for answering all, it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the function needs to be used when returning the value:
`AddTwoNumbers = N1 + N2`

I see where you've gone wrong now I've looked at the link - those are `VB` examples, not `VBA` examples.

Comment: To be more exact, they are VB.Net example.

Comment: Cheers - wasn't sure which flavour of VB it was.